# How to pass a document fetched from firestore to local state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have some documents in firebase firestore.
I am using this javascript function to fetch those

```js
const fetchName = async () => {
      console.log("fetchName fired");
      const snapshot = await db
        .collection("Users")
        .doc(user?.uid)
        .collection("details")
        .doc("data")
        .get();
        // Data is a local state variable
        // SetData is used to manipulate Data
      setData(snapshot.data());
      console.log("Snapped Data: ",snapshot.data());
    console.log("Fetched Data: ",Data);
  };
```

This is the state variable

```js
const [Data, setData] = useState("");
```

I'm passing `fetchName()` function to `useEffect` hook.

```js
useEffect(()=>
  {
    console.log("UseEffect Fired");
    if(user!==null)
    {
      console.log("User not NUll, User->",user);
      fetchName();
    }
  },[user])
```

### The Issue

UseEffect is working correctly and firing `fetchName()` every time user logs in or logs out.
Here the main problem is When use effect is fired I can see `snapshot.data()` fetching the correct data but it is not assigning it to setData(). From hit and trial I have seen `setData()` is fired only the time I make any changes to my code or restart the server.

### Desired Result

But I don't want that I want everytime snapshot.data() fetches the data it should assign it to `Data` using `setData()`

Comment: How do you know this - `but it is not assigning it to setData()`?

Comment: I'm doing console.log to snapshot.data() and Data both. Then I see snapshot.data() has the data I want but setData doesn't fire and I have nothing in Data

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about the 2nd line of `console.log` inside the `fetchName`, you're thinking in a wrong way.

So state updates are asynchronous.

For example,

```
const handleEvent = e => {
    setState(e.target.value);
    console.log(state);  
}
```

This is not going to log the most updated value - this is happening because state updates are asynchronous, so synchronous behavior after a state update shouldn't rely on the state variable to get the most updated value for it.

For deeper explanation, check [here](https://gist.github.com/bpas247/e177a772b293025e5324219d231cf32c) and [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Comment: Sorry the articles just went over my head. I just understood I'm letting react decide when to update the component and state updates are async. Can plase break the whole thing down. Exactly what I'm doing wrong and what needs to be done to fix this

Comment: I can use forceUpdate() here but I don't want to force update it